# Multipart/form-data sends empty data using axios

Tags: node.js, api, rest, axios, multipartform-data

I'm trying to make a request, however, it looks like my body isn't being sent.
I made an API that returns me exactly what I'm sending, however the body is returning empty.

Notes:

1. Through an API, I need to send a file with .txt or .msg format.
2. I have hidden some of the information below as this is sensitive
   business data.

```
const axios = require('axios');

async function UploadFile(urlNovaTarefa, siteUrl, clientId, clientSecret, nomeCentral, grupoId, AssuntoId, usuario, solicitante, copia, solicitacao, anexoNome, anexoConteudo, dataEntrada, enviarNotificacao, cnpjPedido, responsavel){
    // formData
    const form = new FormData();
    form.append('NomeCentral', nomeCentral);
    form.append('GrupoId', grupoId);
    form.append('AssuntoId', AssuntoId);
    form.append('Usuario', usuario);
    form.append('Solicitante', solicitante);
    form.append('Copia', copia); 
    form.append('Solicitacao', solicitacao);
    form.append('AnexoNome', anexoNome);
    form.append('AnexoConteudo', anexoConteudo);
    form.append('DataEntrada', dataEntrada);
    form.append('EnviarNotificacao', enviarNotificacao);
    form.append('CNPJPedido', cnpjPedido);
    form.append('Responsavel', responsavel);

    //console.log(form);
    
    let response = await axios.post(urlNovaTarefa, form, {
          headers: {
            'SiteUrl': siteUrl,
            'Client-Id': clientId,
            'Client-Secret': clientSecret,
            'Content-Type': "multipart/form-data; boundary=CSC",
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': "*",
          },
        });

        let data = response.data;
        console.log(data);
  }


  UploadFile("https://example.net/ct/csc/novaTarefa", "https://example.com/sites/centralcsc/", "1234-1234-1234-1234", "abcd-abcd-abcd-abcd=", "ServicosClientes", "4", "3", "email@example.com", "email@example.com", "email@example.com", "Test", "Test.txt", "C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\Test.txt", "07/10/2021 14:30", "N", "[{\"NumeroCNPJ\":\"12345678910112\",\"NumeroPedido\":[]}]", "email@example.com")
  .then(response => console.log(response))
  .catch(err => console.log(err))
```

What should be being sent on my body (form-data) is this:

```
  '----------------------------553386948041586350665922\r\n' +
    'Content-Disposition: form-data; name="NomeCentral"\r\n' +
    '\r\n',
  'ServicosClientes',
  [Function: bound ],
  '----------------------------553386948041586350665922\r\n' +
    'Content-Disposition: form-data; name="GrupoId"\r\n' +
    '\r\n',
  '4',
  [Function: bound ],
  '----------------------------553386948041586350665922\r\n' +
    'Content-Disposition: form-data; name="AssuntoId"\r\n' +
    '\r\n',
  '3',
  [Function: bound ],
  '----------------------------553386948041586350665922\r\n' +
    'Content-Disposition: form-data; name="Usuario"\r\n' +
    '\r\n',
  'email@example.com',
  [Function: bound ],
  '----------------------------553386948041586350665922\r\n' +
    'Content-Disposition: form-data; name="Solicitante"\r\n' +
    '\r\n',
  'email@example.com',
  [Function: bound ],
  '----------------------------553386948041586350665922\r\n' +
    'Content-Disposition: form-data; name="Copia"\r\n' +
    '\r\n',
  'email@example.com',
  [Function: bound ],
  '----------------------------553386948041586350665922\r\n' +
    'Content-Disposition: form-data; name="Solicitacao"\r\n' +
    '\r\n',
  'Test',
  [Function: bound ],
  '----------------------------553386948041586350665922\r\n' +
    'Content-Disposition: form-data; name="AnexoNome"\r\n' +
    '\r\n',
  'Test.txt',
  [Function: bound ],
  '----------------------------553386948041586350665922\r\n' +
    'Content-Disposition: form-data; name="AnexoConteudo"\r\n' +
    '\r\n',
  'C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\Test.txt',
  [Function: bound ],
  '----------------------------553386948041586350665922\r\n' +
    'Content-Disposition: form-data; name="DataEntrada"\r\n' +
    '\r\n',
  '07/10/2021 14:30',
  [Function: bound ],
  '----------------------------553386948041586350665922\r\n' +
    'Content-Disposition: form-data; name="EnviarNotificacao"\r\n' +
    '\r\n',
  'N',
  [Function: bound ],
  '----------------------------553386948041586350665922\r\n' +
    'Content-Disposition: form-data; name="CNPJPedido"\r\n' +
    '\r\n',
  '[{"NumeroCNPJ":"12345678910112","NumeroPedido":[]}]',
  [Function: bound ],
  '----------------------------553386948041586350665922\r\n' +
    'Content-Disposition: form-data; name="Responsavel"\r\n' +
    '\r\n',
  'email@example.com',
  [Function: bound ]
]
```

This is the return of my API!
The Body is empty.

```
 Resultado: 0,
 Mensagem: 'Success',
 Headers: {
   connection: 'Keep-Alive',
   'transfer-encoding': 'chunked',
   accept: 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
   host: 'example.net',
   'max-forwards': '10',
   'user-agent': 'axios/0.23.0',
   'x-client-ip': '000.00.00.000',
   'x-client-port': '00000',
   siteurl: 'https://example.com/sites/centralcsc/',
   'client-id': '1234-1234-1234-1234',
   'client-secret': 'abcd-abcd-abcd-abcd=',
   'access-control-allow-origin': '*',
   'x-waws-unencoded-url': '/ct/csc/novaTarefa',
   'client-ip': '000.00.00.000:00000',
   'x-arr-log-id': 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
   'disguised-host': 'example.net',
   'x-site-deployment-id': 'example',
   'was-default-hostname': 'example.net',
   'x-original-url': '/ct/csc/novaTarefa',
   'x-forwarded-for': '000.00.00.000:00000',
   'x-arr-ssl': '2048|256|C=US, O=Microsoft Corporation, CN=Microsoft RSA TLS CA 02|CN=*.example.net',
   'x-forwarded-proto': 'https',
   'x-appservice-proto': 'https',
   'x-forwarded-tlsversion': '1.2',
   'request-id': '|999999999-99999999999999.1.',
   'content-type': 'multipart/form-data; boundary=CSC'
 },
 Body: {}
}
undefined
```

Answer (score 1):

Hi  welcome to StackOverflow!

I don't think you're code is wrong, just that your " *I made an API that returns me exactly what I'm sending* " might not be right... if you search for "post bin" you will find a lot of free services that give you a temporary URL so you can send data and check it

one of those services is https://hookbin.com/

I just created a really simple code based on your question:

```js
const axios = require('axios');
const FormData = require('form-data');

async function UploadFile(dataToUpload) {
   const { clientId, clientSecret } = dataToUpload;
    
   const form = new FormData();
   Object.keys(dataToUpload).forEach(key => form.append(key, dataToUpload[key]));

   const response = await axios({
      method: 'POST',
      url: 'https://hookb.in/nPDl9aLjgVsZ7Qrr7ja6',
      data: form,
      headers: {
         ...form.getHeaders(),
         'Client-Id': clientId,
         'Client-Secret': clientSecret,
      },
   });

   console.log(response.data);
}


(async () => {
    await UploadFile({
        clientId: '1234',
        clientSecret: 'abc',
        nomeCentral: 'ServicoClientes',
        grupoId: '4',
        assuntoId: '5',
        usuario: 'email@example.com',
        solicitante: 'email@example.com',
        copia: 'email@example.com',
        solicitacao: 'teste',
        dataEntrada: '07/10/2021 14:30',
        enviarNotificacao: 'N',
        cnpjPedido: '[{\"NumeroCNPJ\":\"12345678910112\",\"NumeroPedido\":[]}]',
        responsavel: 'email@example.com'
    })
})();
```

Note that the code above is the same as below, the code style is just a personal preference

```
await axios.post('https://hookb.in/nPDl9aLjgVsZ7Qrr7ja6', form, {
  headers: {
     ...form.getHeaders(),
     'Client-Id': clientId,
     'Client-Secret': clientSecret,
  },
});
```

and Hookbin does shows all the [data in the body](https://hookbin.com/nPDl9aLjgVsZ7Qrr7ja6/pNNKKje7r)

[image: body screenshot]

---

just to give you some hints on how to improve your code:

- functions should accept max 3 inputs, more than that, try to pass an object as the input, as it will be easier to read and know what the function needs (even better if you use typescript)
- every time you repeating lines, try to come up with something easier, in your example, see my `forEach` loop and I send 1 or 50 properties with just one line
- it's easier to send the date as integer and save that in the database rather than a formated date, as the database could be in a different country and you will start to have issue with conversions, try send, whenever possible something like: `dataEntrada: Date.now()`
- same as boolean values, `enviarNotificacao: 'N'` would be best sent as `enviarNotificacao: false` as it will be easier and faster if you ever need to index that value in the database
- remember that `form.getHeaders()` will automatically append the correct headers on the request, no need to specify more, see the headers in the link or the image below (in case the link expires)

[image: headers screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same issue. I spend my whole day just to get it fixed but in the end I just downgrade my Axios version to ^0.21.4
and it started working like a charm. the problem was the Axios latest version bug.